# How to enable-disable an element in dialog object - DLGEnabled

Tags: dialog, dm-script

Why is the following script not disabling the push button, as  it is supposed to do?

```
class ElementEnableTest : UIFrame {

    void Action( object self ) {
        self.LookUpElement("StopButton").DLGEnabled(0);
        result( "button clicked\n" );
    };

    ElementEnableTest( object self ) {
        TagGroup tgDialog = DLGCreateDialog( "" );
        TagGroup tgButton = DLGCreatePushButton("stop","Action");
        tgButton.DLGIdentifier("StopButton");
        tgDialog.DLGAddElement( tgButton);
        self.init( tgDialog );
        self.Display( "test" );
    };
};

alloc(ElementEnableTest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script action

```
 self.LookUpElement("StopButton").DLGEnabled(0);
```

will set the property value in the associated tagStructure (which describes the dialog), but it does not force an update of the dialog drawing. (Note that other UI commands like `DLGTitle` or `DLGSetProgress` do force an update.)

The command to disable/enable UI elements during display is `SetElementIsEnabled`. So use the following line instead of yours:

```
 self.SetElementIsEnabled("StopButton",0);
```

This will do what you want.

---

A second brute-force way would be to have the dialog window be closed and recreated, but I think you would generally want to avoid this.

```
void Action( object self ) {
    self.LookUpElement("StopButton").DLGEnabled(0);
    self.close()
    self.display("")
    result( "button clicked\n" );
};
```