# How to add content to a visible dialog

Tags: user-interface, dialog, updates, dm-script

How do I add elements to a visible dialog when the user hits a button in dm script?

---

My goal is a input dialog which allows the user to select the images he wants to process. This can be more than one image. Therefore I wanted to design a dialog which offers an *add*-button. Clicking the button adds a selectbox (`DLGCreateImagePopup()`) for choosing the image.

My problem is that I did not find a way to update the dialogs UI. It does not redraw the contents. The only thing that comes close to my problem is in this post about [how to enable and disable an element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28181508/5934316). The post suggests to use `UIFrame.close()` followed by `UIFrame.display()` but the coming up dialog is not modal anymore. Changing the `UIFrame.display()` to `UIFrame.pose()` the dialog just disappears. When trying to execute the script again the error *Class already declared: 'TestDialog'* shows up. I have to restart GMS then.

The following script creates the dialog shown in the image. When clicking 'Add' the line 'Button pressed.' should appear but nothing is happening.

[image: Dialog]

```c
TagGroup dialog_items;
TagGroup dialog_tags = DLGCreateDialog("Test dialog", dialog_items);

TagGroup group = DLGCreateGroup();
group.DLGIdentifier("group");
dialog_items.DLGAddElement(group);

TagGroup label = DLGCreateLabel("Press the 'Add' button.");
group.DLGAddElement(label);

TagGroup add = DLGCreatePushButton("Add", "addButtonPressed");
group.DLGAddElement(add);

class TestDialog : UIFrame{
    void addButtonPressed(object self){
        TagGroup g = self.LookUpElement("group");
        TagGroup l = DLGCreateLabel("Button pressed.");
        g.DLGAddElement(l);

        self.ValidateView(); // <- does nothing

        // self.close();
        // self.display(""); // <- doesn't show as modal

        // self.close();
        // self.pose(); // <- doesn't show up, forces to restart GMS
    }
}

Object dialog = alloc(TestDialog).init(dialog_tags);

dialog.Pose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The script dialog model in DM-scripting is very limited and **does not support adding or removing items during display** (as of GMS 3.4).

It's maybe possible to work around that issue with a lot of effort, but overall spending too much time on making script dialogs "pretty" is most often not worth it.

The best you can possibly do quickly is to utilized the *shown* attribute of existing items to display or hide them.

See example:

```
class CElementHideTest : UIframe
{
    TagGroup BuildDialog(object self)
    {
        TagGroup dlg,dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("test",dlgitems)

        TagGroup group = DLGCreateGroup().DLGIdentifier("group")
        dlgitems.DLGAddElement(group)

        TagGroup label = DLGCreateLabel("Toggle tests")
        group.DLGAddElement(label)

        TagGroup toggleEnabledButton = DLGCreatePushButton("Toggle Enabled", "toggleEnabled")
        group.DLGAddElement(toggleEnabledButton)

        TagGroup toggleShownButton = DLGCreatePushButton("Toggle Shown", "toggleShown")
        group.DLGAddElement(toggleShownButton)

        TagGroup field1 = DLGCreateIntegerField(5,5).DLGIdentifier("field")
        dlgitems.DLGAddElement(field1)

        return dlg
    }

    void toggleEnabled(object self)
    {
        number is = self.GetElementIsEnabled("field")
        self.SetElementIsEnabled("field",!is)
    }

    void toggleShown(object self)
    {
        number is = self.GetElementIsShown("field")
        self.SetElementIsShown("field",!is)
    }

    object Init(object self)
    {
        return self.Init(self.BuildDialog())
    }
}

Alloc(CElementHideTest).init().Pose()
```

[image]
[image]

While it is possible to resize a dialog window while being displayed, this is not much of use for a modal dialog, because the position of the OK | Cancel buttons is fixed at startup. Hence you can only create an "ugly" dialog with lots of empty space where items will appear.

However, if your script is run on a background-thread, then you can create your own modal-dialog as in the example below. This would allow you to use a window resize and shrink/extend the dialog when you display items.

Note, that this can not work on a script in the main-thread, as the dialog-display code *also* runs on the main thread. Hence waiting on a dialog would prevent the dialog from being displayed properly.

```
Class CScriptModalDialog : UIFrame
{
    object contSignal

    TagGroup BuildDialog(object self)
    {
        TagGroup dlg,dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("test",dlgitems)

        TagGroup group = DLGCreateGroup().DLGIdentifier("group")
        dlgitems.DLGAddElement(group)

        TagGroup label = DLGCreateLabel("Display as modal dialog")
        group.DLGAddElement(label)

        TagGroup toggleEnabledButton = DLGCreatePushButton("Continue", "ContinuePressed")
        group.DLGAddElement(toggleEnabledButton)

        contSignal = NewSignal(0)

        return dlg
    }

    void ContinuePressed(object self)
    {
        contSignal.SetSignal()
    }

    number PoseScriptDlg(object self, number timeOutSec )
    {
        self.Init(self.BuildDialog())
        self.Display("Script dialog")
        object cancelSignal = NewCancelSignal()
        number success = contSignal.WaitOnSignal(timeOutSec,cancelSignal)   // Could also use Infinity() as timeout
        self.Close()
        return success
    }

    number WaitOnOK(object self)
    {
        object cancelSignal = NewCancelSignal()
        return contSignal.WaitOnSignal(1,cancelSignal)
    }
}

class CMain
{
    object continueDlg
    CMain(object self) { continueDlg=Alloc(CScriptModalDialog); }

    void RunMethod(object self)
    {
        ClearResults()
        Result("Waiting on user for 3 sec...\n")
        if ( continueDlg.PoseScriptDlg(3) )
            Result("Continue\n")
        else
            Result("TimeOut\n")
    }
}

Alloc(CMain).StartThread("RunMethod")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will then use your proposed sulution.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, and possibly not what you want, but as an idea-giver: 
If you are only interested in choosing up-to four images, one can also get a bit creative with the existing `Get...Images()` commands, like f.e:

```
image img1,img2,img3,img4
if (GetFourlabeledImagesWithPrompt( "Select up to 4 images.\nDouble selected images will be used once.","Titel", "first:",img1, "second:",img2,"third:",img3,"fourth:",img4))
{
    // Make list of used ID's removing doubles
    taggroup list = NewTagGroup()
    list.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( img1.ImageGetLabel(), 1 )
    list.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( img2.ImageGetLabel(), 1 )
    list.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( img3.ImageGetLabel(), 1 )
    list.TagGroupSetTagAsBoolean( img4.ImageGetLabel(), 1 )

    number nUsed = list.TagGroupCountTags()
    Result("\n Unique images chosen: " + nUsed)
    for( number i=0; i<nUsed; i++)
    {
        image img := FindImageByLabel( list.TagGroupGetTagLabel(i) )
        if ( img.ImageIsValid() )
        {
            Result("\n\t Image #"+i+": <"+img.ImageGetName()+">" )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]